# Python spews out a bunch of information after running any commands/scripts

Tags: python

Whenever I run a python script, a lot of information is thrown out before executing anything. See below.
What is causing this to happen when I run anything? ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎ ‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

```
py -v
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import _imp # builtin
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_warnings' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import '_frozen_importlib_external' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
import '_io' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'marshal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'nt' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _thread # previously loaded ('_thread')
import '_thread' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import _weakref # previously loaded ('_weakref')
import '_weakref' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'winreg' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installing zipimport hook
import 'time' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.FrozenImporter'>
# installed zipimport hook
# C:\Python38\lib\encodings\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\encodings\__init__.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\__init__.cpython-38.pyc'
# C:\Python38\lib\__pycache__\codecs.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\codecs.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\__pycache__\\codecs.cpython-38.pyc'
import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'codecs' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA49F0A00>
# C:\Python38\lib\encodings\__pycache__\aliases.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\encodings\aliases.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\aliases.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'encodings.aliases' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA4A0EFD0>
import 'encodings' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA49F07F0>
# C:\Python38\lib\encodings\__pycache__\utf_8.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\encodings\utf_8.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\utf_8.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'encodings.utf_8' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA49F0880>
# C:\Python38\lib\encodings\__pycache__\cp1252.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\cp1252.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'encodings.cp1252' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA4A27100>
import '_signal' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# C:\Python38\lib\encodings\__pycache__\latin_1.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\encodings\latin_1.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\encodings\\__pycache__\\latin_1.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'encodings.latin_1' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA4A27490>
# C:\Python38\lib\__pycache__\io.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\io.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\__pycache__\\io.cpython-38.pyc'
# C:\Python38\lib\__pycache__\abc.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\abc.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\__pycache__\\abc.cpython-38.pyc'
import '_abc' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA4A27940>
import 'io' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA4A27640>
# C:\Python38\lib\__pycache__\site.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\site.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\__pycache__\\site.cpython-38.pyc'
# C:\Python38\lib\__pycache__\os.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\os.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\__pycache__\\os.cpython-38.pyc'
# C:\Python38\lib\__pycache__\stat.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\stat.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\__pycache__\\stat.cpython-38.pyc'
import '_stat' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'stat' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA4A4C3A0>
# C:\Python38\lib\__pycache__\ntpath.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\ntpath.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\__pycache__\\ntpath.cpython-38.pyc'
# C:\Python38\lib\__pycache__\genericpath.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\genericpath.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\__pycache__\\genericpath.cpython-38.pyc'
import 'genericpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA4A5C100>
import 'ntpath' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA4A4C430>
# C:\Python38\lib\__pycache__\_collections_abc.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\_collections_abc.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\__pycache__\\_collections_abc.cpython-38.pyc'
import '_collections_abc' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA4A4CF10>
import 'os' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA4A32A60>
# C:\Python38\lib\__pycache__\_sitebuiltins.cpython-38.pyc matches C:\Python38\lib\_sitebuiltins.py
# code object from 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\__pycache__\\_sitebuiltins.cpython-38.pyc'
import '_sitebuiltins' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA4A445B0>
import 'site' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x000001ADA4A32340>
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import 'atexit' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
>>>
```

And whenever I run 'exit()' this happens:

```
>>> exit()
# clear __builtin__._
# clear sys.path
# clear sys.argv
# clear sys.ps1
# clear sys.ps2
# clear sys.exitfunc
# clear sys.exc_type
# clear sys.exc_value
# clear sys.exc_traceback
# clear sys.last_type
# clear sys.last_value
# clear sys.last_traceback
# clear sys.path_hooks
# clear sys.path_importer_cache
# clear sys.meta_path
# clear sys.flags
# clear sys.float_info
# restore sys.stdin
# restore sys.stdout
# restore sys.stderr
# cleanup __main__
# cleanup[1] locale
# cleanup[1] functools
# cleanup[1] encodings
# cleanup[1] site
# cleanup[1] sysconfig
# cleanup[1] operator
# cleanup[1] abc
# cleanup[1] _weakrefset
# cleanup[1] sre_constants
# cleanup[1] re
# cleanup[1] _codecs
# cleanup[1] nt
# cleanup[1] _warnings
# cleanup[1] zipimport
# cleanup[1] encodings.cp1252
# cleanup[1] _functools
# cleanup[1] _locale
# cleanup[1] signal
# cleanup[1] traceback
# cleanup[1] encodings.aliases
# cleanup[1] exceptions
# cleanup[1] _weakref
# cleanup[1] sre_compile
# cleanup[1] encodings.cp850
# cleanup[1] _sre
# cleanup[1] codecs
# cleanup[1] sre_parse
# cleanup[2] copy_reg
# cleanup[2] types
# cleanup[2] errno
# cleanup[2] _abcoll
# cleanup[2] ntpath
# cleanup[2] genericpath
# cleanup[2] stat
# cleanup[2] warnings
# cleanup[2] UserDict
# cleanup[2] os.path
# cleanup[2] linecache
# cleanup[2] os
# cleanup sys
# cleanup __builtin__
# cleanup ints: 19 unfreed ints
# cleanup floats
```

Comment: The `-v` stands for verbose in your command, which tells Python to print additional details.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I understand, but why is it telling me all these other informations?

Comment: From the docs: ` -v
Print a message each time a module is initialized, showing the place (filename or built-in module) from which it is loaded. When given twice (-vv), print a message for each file that is checked for when searching for a module. Also provides information on module cleanup at exit. See also PYTHONVERBOSE. `

Comment: @mgrollins Okay, thanks. What about the `exit()` "problem" ?

Comment: exit() is giving you more output because you opened the python shell in verbose mode

Comment: From the docs:  -v Print a message each time a module is initialized, showing the place (filename or built-in module) from which it is loaded. When given twice (-vv), print a message for each file that is checked for when searching for a module. **Also provides information on module cleanup at exit.** See also PYTHONVERBOSE.   https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/cmdline.html#id4

Comment: I actually encountered the same problem because I ran `python -v` thinking I was going to get a version (which is NOT that but rather `python --version`), then forgot I had opened the REPL that way and wondered what on earth was going on. Googled some of the output and found this. So this question actually helped me, +1

Answer (score 1):

Since you opened the python shell in verbose mode, you'll get extra output pertaining to all the modules and garbage collection that's happening when you open and exit the shell.

If you do exit() without opening the python shell in verbose mode, you'll get no exit output.